# Hide previosly selected dropdown on a datepicker in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I don't know how to hide a little dropdown , below the picker with previously selected date.
Here is the image:

[image: dropdown suggestion]

I use Google Chrome as a web browser. This is a bootstrap datepicker with bootstrap validation.

Comment: Can you paste a bit of your code? You could simply remove the `<input...>` tab from your HTML code and remove the call in your JavaScript file.

Answer (score 0):

Fot that you must use the [`autocomplete`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp) attribute of `HTML`

On your input set it like this:

```
<input type="yourtype" autocomplete="off">
```

> The autocomplete attribute specifies whether or not an input field
>   should have autocomplete enabled.
>
> Autocomplete allows the browser to predict the value. When a user
>   starts to type in a field, the browser should display options to fill
>   in the field, based on earlier typed values.
>
> Note: The autocomplete attribute works with the following 
>   types: text, search, url, tel, email, password, datepickers, range,
>   and color.